# Get windows username using typescript or javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In my angular 4 application I want to get windows username. Is it possible with typescript or java-script ? I am using the Chrome browser.

Comment: why would you need a user's Windows username for your angular app?

Answer (score 5):

For security measures, I don't think it's possible to get the windows OS user information from browser using javascript/typescript.

Comment: But it is possible with languages like c#. Why it is not with javascript?

Comment: @SushaniNimesha Since when does C# run in browsers?

Comment: Is there any browser plugin that I can use for this?

Comment: C# is used on the server side and not in the browser/client. You can call the server side code from javascript if the server is running on the same machine to get the user info.

Comment: Got it. In this application client and server are running on two different machines.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered creating your application in **[Electron](https://electronjs.org/)**?

> Electron is an open source library developed by GitHub for building cross-platform desktop applications with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. Electron accomplishes this by combining Chromium and Node.js into a single runtime and apps can be packaged for Mac, Windows, and Linux.

Electron does not have the same security restrictions and you can still use **Angular 4**

If you choose to use **Electron** you can get userinfo through node.js [os](https://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os_userinfo_options) module:

> The os.userInfo() method returns information about the currently
>   effective user